# Using MyBatis to Insert into Sybase table with IDENTITY column as ID. How do I get ID returned?

Tags: sybase, identity, mybatis

I need to get the auto generated ID when doing the insert below. The insertRecord method returns the number of rows written. That is fine and expected. The Object Log, however, does not have it's id field updated to the auto generated ID. Any ideas?

```
CREATE TABLE LOG
(
  ID            NUMERIC(20,0) IDENTITY,
  NAME          VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION   VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  USR           VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL
)

public class Log
{
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private String user;
  //getters+setters......
}

int insertRecord(@Param("log") Log log);

<insert id="insertRecord" parameterType="com.xxx.yyy.zzz.model.Log" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id">
  INSERT INTO LOG (NAME, DESCRIPTION, USR)
  VALUES (#{log.name}, #{log.description}, #{log.user})
  <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="long">
    select @@identity
  </selectKey>
</insert>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

The keyProperty in the select needed to be log.id. See below.

```
<selectKey keyProperty="log.id" resultType="long">
  select @@identity AS id
</selectKey>
```